# Duration between two dates Java

Tags: java, datetime, between, duration

I have DateTime string 2020-04-03 01:29:27 and 2020-04-03 01:29:37
I want to get duration in hours. I have tried many things but this but cant find any help

Answer (score 5):

> I have tried many things but this but cant find any help

Do these "many things" include [consulting the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofDays-int-) where you would find that:

```
// assuming both dates are in d1 and d2

Duration duration = Duration.between(d1, d2);

long hours = duration.toHours();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### *java.time*

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-04-03 01:29:27", formatter);
        LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-04-03 01:29:37", formatter);
        System.out.printf("%.4f Hour(s)", Duration.between(dt1, dt2).toSeconds() / 3600.0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.0028 Hour(s)
```

Learn more about ***java.time*** API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: And others whinge about it, eh?

Comment: @hd1 - I didn't understand your comment. I tried to understand your comment by going through your answer but I couldn't make anything out of your comment. If your comment is about why I have used `.toSeconds() / 3600.0`, the answer is: purposefully. Had I used `Duration.between(dt1, dt2).toHours()`, it would have returned `0`.